# Format Google Spreadsheet JSON repsonse for chart

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am making API request to Google sheets and I want to visualise data from table into chart but I can't manage to convert the response JSON into usable one for the chart. I want to get every row of the table in different array with the name of row and the contents of the row as shown bellow.

This is what I receive from the API:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => 99.39%
            [B] => 91.27%
            [C] => 94.44%
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => 49.19%
            [B] => 19.25%
            [C] => 62.11%
        )
    ...........
)
```

And I want to transform it into this:
I just want to separate every column. name: A, data: 99.39%, 49.19% .., then name: B, data: 1, 2 ......

```
series: [{
        title: 'A',
        data: ['99.39%', '49.19%']

    }, {
        title: 'B',
        data: [.....]

    }, {
        title: 'C',
        data: [.....]

    }, {

       ....

    }]
```

I tried to do it this way but it wasn't successfull:

```
foreach ($rawData as $subarray) {

    $converted_subarray = array_map('floatval', $subarray);

    $series[] = [
        'name' => key($converted_subarray),
        'data' => array_values($converted_subarray),
    ];

}
```

The result I got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 99.39%
                    [1] => 91.27%
                    [2] => 94.44%

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
            [data] => Array
                (

                  [0] => 49.19%
                  [1] => 19.25%
                  [2] => 62.11%

                )

        )
    .....
)
```

The main problem I have is that the 'name' value doesn't change to A, B, C ... but it stays A

Comment: Please place the part of the code where you're adding series data to Google Spreadsheets API library. It will helps a lot.

Comment: Where is the name attribute supposed to come from?  Because item 1 has keys A, B, C but item 2 also has A, B, C.  So it's just applying an arbitrary letter depending on which order they are processed in?

Comment: @James A, B, C are the names of the columns. And every item is new row in the table. So for example column A has values 99.39%, 49.19% ...

Comment: Right, but what you want is a thing called "A" that has columns A, B, C in it - so not just "A" - so why is it called "A"

Comment: @James I just want to separate every column. name: A, data: 99.39%, 49.19% .., then name: B, data: 1, 2 ......

Comment: Please update your question, "what I want to transform it into" is different.

Comment: @James well, I have shown how I want it to look like

Comment: You said you want `{title: 'A', data: ['99.39%', '91.27%', '94.44%']}` not `{title: 'A', data: ['99.39%', '49.19%']}` - the numbers are different and so is the logic required.

Comment: @James ohhh right. I got it. My mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you

```php
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'A' => 12,
        'B' => 13,
        'C' => 14,
    ],
    [
        'A' => 15,
        'B' => 16,
        'C' => 17,
    ]
];

$keys = [];
foreach ($array as $element) {
    foreach ($element as $key => $subElementValue) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $keys)) {
            $keys[$key][] =  $subElementValue;
        } else {
            $keys[$key] = [];
            $keys[$key][] =  $subElementValue;
        }
    }
}

print_r($keys);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 15
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 16
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 17
        )
)
```

This script iterate your array and just check and update the `$key` array and then make the final array which is you mentioned in your question

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot.